# How to show if this set is closed or not?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

Be $$A = \left\{(-1)^n \left(1 + \frac{2}{n+1}\right),\ n\in\mathbb{N}\right\}$$

How to show if it's closed or not?

**attempts**

I wrote it as

$$A = \left\{(-1)^n \left(\frac{n+3}{n+1}\right),\ n\in\mathbb{N}\right\}$$
I thought about some qualitative analysis like: as $n\to +\infty$ I obtain $\pm 1$, and I would think then I could write $A$ as

$$A = \left(-2, -1) \cup (1, \frac{5}{3}\right)$$

which is a union of opens, hence it's open.

Or again, since $\partial A \not \in A$ can I conclude the set is not closed.

Or else I also know that a set is closed iff it contains ALL its limit points.
I think that $1$ is a limit point for $A$ since $\forall \epsilon$ I can always find a ball $B = (1, \epsilon) \ni p$ where $p$ is a point in $A$.

Am I right or wrong?

That was an intuition, but how to prove that $1$ is indeed a limit point?

Comment: $1=\lim (-1)^{2n}\frac {2n+3} {2n+1}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A\subseteq\mathbb R$ where $\mathbb R$ is equipped with its usual topology.

The elements $+1$ and $-1$ are limit points of $A$ that are not elements of $A$. This tells us that $A$ is not closed.

Let me say also that $A$ is countable and not empty and in the usual topology on $\mathbb R$ such sets are not open. Note that they cannot be the superset of any open interval because open intervals are not countable.

Comment: That was enlightening. I did not know about the countable part, so thank you very much!!

Comment: You are very welcome.